# API call not working on a particular network

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I am currently doing a project on building a weather app as part of my internship program in a company.I am using openweathermap API for getting the weather data from their servers.Below is the example of the API that I am using.

[http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bangalore&appid=8eca04841762dd31f99510429e97970a][1]

The problem is that the API request is failing(Getting 503:Service Unavailable Error) when I am using it on the computer browser that is connected to their network.But the same is working fine when I am using it on my phone browser which is on a different network.So can anyone suggest me on how to overcome this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have the app registered for domain you call it from?

Comment: No not yet.I am just checking out if the link is working fine or not in my browser. I am using API provided by this website :- http://www.openweathermap.com/current

Comment: Could you post the relevant code ?